# Possible to check return type of a function?

Tags: c, types, void-pointers

Let's say I have a function..

void * getValue(...);

Is there a way that I check for the return type of a call to getValue(...) ?

I plan on using a void* method such as getValue() in a program and the process of my program will be dependent on the return type of getValue().

Is it possible to check for return type?

Comment: If I understood your problem, you want to create two functions with the same name but with different return types? If so, unless your two methods have a different numbers of params or with different types, you can't differentiate them since method signatures in C takes the name of the method and its number and types of params.

Comment: essentially... it's probably best to just write 2 separate functions

Comment: Probably yes, or maybe you can use a structure as @pmg said

Comment: @BrendanRius: I assume you're confusing C and C++ here.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to return a structure instead

```
enum valuetype {PCHAR, PSHORT, PINT, PLONG, PLLONG, PFLOAT, PDOUBLE, PLDOUBLE};
struct sometype {
    enum valuetype vt;
    void *value;
}
struct sometype getValue(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's no way you can tell exactly what's stored in a (void *) pointer. If you want my advise, change your code and use proper typed pointers

Comment: I will take your advice* :)

Answer (score 2):

No - C does not tag values with their type, so the information is not available.

Possible alternatives include adding an out parameter to the function to indicate the type, or making/using a variant struct that includes both the value and an enum indicating its type.